# Float a Div Next to a Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to have a div that will hold my ad and float to the right  of the page. I want the table and text in the main body to be to the left of the ad and then extend all the way to the right of the page when the ad ends.

The problem is there is a table in the main body and it will not display to the left of the div. It displays below it. How do I fix this?

```
<p> 
    <div style="margin:5px; float:right;">
        <img src="ad.jpg" height="600" width="160">
    </div>         
    blah blah blah
    <table width="100%">
        <tr><td>dsf</td></tr>
    </table> 
    the table because of the 100% appears below the div 
    for the ad.jpg instead of to the left of it
</p>
```

Comment: display:inline should work think so

Comment: Isn't the width of table + floated div > available space?

Comment: close the img: <img src="ad.jpg" height="600" width="160"/>
if your table takes the 100% where do you want to put the div?

Comment: @MCSI images don't need to be closed; they're void elements. Many browsers will have troubles with not closing the `<p>` though. And of course you're right about the width of the table.

Comment: @WeldonJohnson Where do you want the "blah blah blah" text to appear that is between the div and the table? And you're not clearing the float, so if the image is higher than the table, where do you want the rest of the content to appear?

Comment: you are right @MrLister! but I thought that IE have some troubles with this

Comment: I think what @WeldonJohnson wants is that the table has a dynamic with

Comment: @MCSI why did you think that? IE is far from perfect, but it handles the basic constructs well enough. Otherwise all websites would always be a horrible mess with IE!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10438/discussion-between-mcsi-and-mr-lister)

Comment: @MCSI No, I'm not much of a chatter.

Answer (score 5):

Add display:inline css for the table!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the table in another div and use clear property in the first div

Comment: i ended up doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5G7RV/ enclosing the table in a div and styling the table div .table{overflow:hidden;}​